# Word order for "What we can do as <noun>"

Tags: word-order

Which is better:

1. `What can we do as doctors to improve health?`
2. `What can we do to improve health as doctors?`

I think #1 is better because it's clearer that `doctors` is referring to `we`.

Comment: Agreed, #1 better.

Comment: *What can we as doctors do...?*

Comment: There are cases where it would mean different things e.g. "What can we do as doctors to improve training?" could be training for anything vs "What can we do to improve training as doctors?" suggests medical school. But meaning is the same here.